Problems publishing to a private npm registry (CodeArtifacts) using Lerna
I'm looking to move from public npm registry to private npm registry hosted in AWS.
The cmd that we are using to publish to a  private registry is
lerna publish --conventional-commits --conventional-graduate --yes --message "Publish [skip ci]" --no-commit-hooks --pre-dist-tag alpha --registry https:// --loglevel 3 --force-publish
However I'm getting no diff found which results in zero packages published to the private registry
lerna info Graduating all prereleased packages
lerna info Looking for changed packages since @xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx@24.3.7
lerna sill checking diff xxxxxxx
Any thoughts on how to publish to a private registry?
I've already tried the --force-publish flag  option without any luck

Hi, please see formatting help
